# Error: ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I have a web application with Vuejs and Laravel
I would like to use CKEditor 5

I installed dependencies with

```
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

like mentionned in the doc
[here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/vuejs.html#using-component-locally)

and In my component:

```
<script>
    import draggable from 'vuedraggable'
    import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue'
    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic'

    export default {
        components: {
            draggable,
            ckeditor: CKEditor.component
        },
        data() {
            return {

                editor: ClassicEditor,
                editorConfig: {

                }
            }
        },
```

and I have this error message:

```
Error: ckeditor-duplicated-modules: Some CKEditor 5 modules are duplicated
```

I've already try these recommendations:

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

or remove package-lock.json

in doc [here](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/support/error-codes.html#error-ckeditor-duplicated-modules)

But I have always the same error message

has someone an idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Can Found any solution?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was accidentally requiring the wrong version of a CKEditor plugin.

I had this:

```
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment": "^28.0.0",  // This was the plugin I tried to install
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat": "^27.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^27.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote": "^27.1.0",
"@ckeditor/ckeditor5-ckfinder": "^27.1.0",
```

And the issue went away when I changed the `28.0` to `27.1`

Comment: same issue, I installed a lot of modules with out specify the version, and all of them were installed with version `^35.2.1`... then I installed independently another module `@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font` with `npm install`. But it installed with version `^35.3.0`. So I modified manually the version in the `package.json` to had the same version. Then `npm i` command, `npm run serve` (if it is your case), and that's it.